# Disable brace indentation for JS in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I write braces they end up indented like this:

```
ClassName =
    {
    };
```

I quite hate that. I want it like this:

```
ClassName =
{
};
```

It worked like that in VS 2015. But with 2017 it behaves crazy.

I have fiddled every parameter under Options > Text Editor > Javascript/Typescript but nothing makes it behave.

I still would like braces to auto format, if that's possible.

Comment: This is killing me to. Definitely new behavior in 2017, and I feel like only after one of the service packs was installed (was not in first release of 2017 I am pretty sure). The only solution I found is to put opening brace on same line instead of newline. what makes it annoying is that it changes existing code which messes with diff tools / source control